# Freemember reset password email link missing hash/session

Tags: freemember

We have an EE 2.5.5 installation using Freemember 2.2.2.

On the password reset, the email sent is missing the hash/session gobblety goop. Looks like this:

http://domain.com/home/password_reset

instead of this

http://domain.com/home/password_reset/sir9vcplhnex

We have several sites with this functioning perfectly, so I'm sort of at a loss.

Comment: Can you check the `exp_reset_password` database table and see whether a valid reset token is actually being generated and added for your member_id? Does this happen for all members? Do you have PHP errors enabled?

Comment: Are you using the [example reset password form](https://github.com/expressodev/freemember/blob/master/docs/reset_password_tag.md#reset-password-form-fields) as a guide? Would you be able to copy in your EE code in your question so we can see how things are being requested?

Comment: Sorry for responding in the wrong area. It occurred before morning coffee had kicked in. I've solved our issue. It turned out to be an accidentally modified variable in the email notifications template for Forgotten Password Instructions.